# How to customize url like /users/Tom with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I am using Rails to develop a project.I want to change this url

**http://my_domain/users/1**

to

**http://my_domain/users/Tom**

The 1 is **id**,and the Tom is **name** in the database.

How to realize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller:

```
def to_param
  “#{name}”
end
```

Now you can find users by

```
@users = User.find_by_name(params[:id])
```

In the view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
...
<%= link_to "Detail", user_path(user.name) %>
<% end %>
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

[Friendly ID gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) ia pretty good for that. [Here's](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid) a Railscast descibing what to do.